# Colour for R code chunk in listings package

Tags: r, latex, listings

I wish to insert a R code chunk in a LaTeX document. The default settings for the `listings` package also changes the font, but not the colour, which I need.

Although I understand that I can set the colours using the `lstset` function, I am not very sure of the combination that would look good. Thus, can anyone share their `lstset` settings for the `listings` package to colour R syntax? This way everyone who sees this post can use the same settings!

Comment: Take a look at knitr. Chunk options: `eval=FALSE`, `highlight=TRUE` should suffice.

Comment: Actually, I would prefer to use listings as that can wrap my code. Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}    

\lstset{ 
  language=R,                     % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{Blue},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1, each line
                                  % will be numbered
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},      % keyword style
  commentstyle=\color{YellowGreen},   % comment style
  stringstyle=\color{ForestGreen}      % string literal style
} 


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
library(foreign)

foo <- rnorm(100)
# writing a function
bar <- apply(foo, 1, function(x){
  y <- sqrt(x)
  cat(paste('The result is ', x )))
})
bar

str(bar)

foo + bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]