# Problem with R chunk output which spans more than one page in Quarto PDF

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, quarto

The output of an R chunk, which extends beyond a single page in a Quarto PDF, does not display correctly, as shown in the following R code output.

How can I correctly render it?

````
---
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "MYaseen208"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3

execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---


# Experimental Planning & Layout

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(eda4treeR)
```

```{r}
#| label: Reading-Packages
#| output: false
```

## Example 2.1 (Pg. 22)

::: callout-tip
## Example 2.1 (Pg. 22)

A field trial was planted to compare a seedlot derived from a seed orchard (SO) with one collected from a routine population (P). There were eight plots of each seedlot, thinned at seven year of age. Tree diameters at breast height (dbh) were measured at 15 years and plot means calculated. An `R` program to carry out a Completely Randomized Analysis of plot means is given below:


```{r}
#| class-output: r
options(continue = " ", prompt   = " ")
example(
    topic          = "Exam2.1"
  , package        = "eda4treeR"
  , lib.loc        = NULL
  , character.only = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , give.lines     = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , local          = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , type           = c("console", "html")[2]
  , echo           = c(TRUE, FALSE)[1]
  , verbose        = getOption("verbose")
  , setRNG         = c(TRUE, FALSE)[1]
  , ask            = getOption("example.ask")
  , prompt.prefix  = NULL
  , run.dontrun    = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , run.donttest   = interactive()
  )
```
:::

## Example 2.2 (Pg. 24)

::: callout-tip
## Example 2.2 (Pg. 24)

A field trial was planted to compare a seedlot derived from a seed orchard (SO) with one collected from a routine population (P). There were eight plots of each seedlot, thinned at seven year of age. Tree diameters at breast height (dbh) were measured at 15 years and plot means calculated. An `R` program to carry out a Randomized Complete Block Analysis of plot means is given below:


```{r}
#| class-output: r
options(continue = " ", prompt   = " ")
example(
    topic          = "Exam2.2"
  , package        = "eda4treeR"
  , lib.loc        = NULL
  , character.only = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , give.lines     = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , local          = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , type           = c("console", "html")[2]
  , echo           = c(TRUE, FALSE)[1]
  , verbose        = getOption("verbose")
  , setRNG         = c(TRUE, FALSE)[1]
  , ask            = getOption("example.ask")
  , prompt.prefix  = NULL
  , run.dontrun    = c(TRUE, FALSE)[2]
  , run.donttest   = interactive()
  )
```

:::
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the pdf option `listings: true` such that your output is displayed correctly, however, you need to apply some additional styling to mirror the style of `class-output: r` (See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402157/colour-for-r-code-chunk-in-listings-package)).

```
---
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    listings: true
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}    
          \lstset{ 
            language=R,                     % the language of the code
            basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
            numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
            numberstyle=\tiny\color{Blue},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
            stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1, each line
                                            % will be numbered
            numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
            backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
            showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
            showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
            showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
            frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
            rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
            tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
            captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
            breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
            breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
            keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},      % keyword style
            commentstyle=\color{YellowGreen},   % comment style
            stringstyle=\color{ForestGreen}      % string literal style
          } 


execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Julian for your answer. I am getting the following error: compilation failed- error
`LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.86 \lstset
            { 
`. Any thoughts please.

Comment: which quarto version are you using?

Comment: I am using `Quarto 1.3.361`. Removing the options `usenames,dvipsnames` worked for me. Thanks